# JS - If it contains text in class x, then it takes the value from class y

Tags: javascript

Ahoy, I have a question regarding JS, more specifically, I have a situation like below in the code and I would like to create a script that if there is a value of Xx in class X, it gets me the value of Yy from class Y. In this case, it is about "Color" and "Black".

```html
<div class="dictionary__param row mb-2">
  <div class="dictionary__name col-4 col-md-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
    <span class="dictionary__name_txt">Kolor</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dictionary__values col-7 col-md-8">
    <div class="dictionary__value">
      <span class="dictionary__value_txt">czarny</span>
      <div class="dictionary__description --value"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your provided example. Is Xx a property or a class or a text or an element? Is X an element or the class collection? Same for Yy and Y. What is about Color and Black? What is a concrete example in your provided markup? I cannot find Color or Black in there.

Comment: Sorry, i mean "Kolor" and "czarny"

Comment: Can you name the classes you want to check?